# HTMLElement.innerHTML adding attributes to </span> closing tag, and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I am using Angular 13 with a pipe to reformat text in a `contenteditable` `div`. Everything is working fine until the `innerHtml` is replaced with the new code. The attributes from the last child node (a `span` tag) are appended to the inside of the closing `span` tag. I have no idea why this is happening.

I'm using TypeScript, with Angular 13, on Chromium (MS Edge) v97.0.1072.76 and Firefox v95.0.

Here's an example:

```
reformatContent(event: Event) {
const el = (event.target as HTMLElement);

const originalHtml = el.innerHTML;
console.log(originalHtml); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass">More Text</span>

const newHtml = this.reformatText(originalHtml);
console.log(newHtml); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass someNewClass">More Text</span> <-- this is ok, what I expected.

el.innerHTML= newHtml;
console.log(el.innerHTML); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass someNewClass">More Text</span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass someNewClass"> <-- why is this happening???
}
```

I just want to be clear that the `originalHtml` includes the close `</span>` tag. So I don't think the browser is trying to close the tag.

Edit for typo.

Edit 2:
I updated the original code for typos and to make it more clear how I was getting the innerHTML. I didn't think that was where the problem was, but apparently that's it, because this works:

```
reformatContent(event: Event) {
const e = (event.target as HTMLElement);
const el = document.getElementById(e.id);

const originalHtml = el.innerHTML;
console.log(originalHtml); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass">More Text</span>

const newHtml = this.reformatText(originalHtml);
console.log(newHtml); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass someNewClass">More Text</span> <-- this is ok, what I expected.

el.innerHTML= newHtml;
console.log(el.innerHTML); // "Some text <span id="someTextId" class="someTextClass someNewClass">More Text</span> <-- now it works
}
```

I don't understand why the original way of getting the element caused this problem. I fixed it, but I'd really like to understand what's happening here.

Comment: You have a typo error. The property name is `innerHTML`. while you are accessing `innerHtml`

Comment: I don't know why it was happening, but I solved it. My el was actually being provided from an event (event.target as HTMLElement). I'm not sure why, but this was causing the problem. I've edited the post to show what happened. I'm still curious as to why the problem was occurring in the first place.

Pankaj, yes, there is a typo in the post. My actual code is innerHTML. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This whole approach seems weird. Why not use proper dom operators? Looks like you’re just adding a class?

Answer (score 1):

What is reformatText function?

```
this.reformatText(originalHtml)
```

This function is changing your span and your bug is from here.

You might say that your result are right but you are using console.log on an invalid variable (originalHtml)

What is and where is originalHtml?

But generally what I know, your problem is because of this line:

```
const newHtml = this.reformatText(originalHtml);
```

Comment: Seems so. Probably replacing everything that comes after 'span' so treats both the opening and closing 'span' as a thing to replace.

Comment: I didn't include the reformatText because it's pretty extensive. However, I don't think that's the problem because what it produces is correct. It isn't until I replace the innerHTML with it that it becomes a problem. Also, I figured out how to fix it, although I don't understand why it was happening in the first place. See my updated post.